# Shiny app doesn't wont running on the salesforce database

Tags: r, salesforce, shiny

I have question about connection beetewen Salesforce database and Shiny app. I found some information here [enter link description here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/tWOIKnkb8No) but it was two years ago. In my app I have this comunicat: `NOT_FOUND: The requested resource does not exist`. Is there any solution for this problem. I am new in Salesforce.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: You need to check properties with which your app connects to SF, specially Salesforce URL.

Comment: I use this solution: shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  username <- " ... "
  password <- " ... "
  instanceURL <- "https://eu4.salesforce.com/"
  apiVersion <- "26.0"
  session <- rforcecom.login(username, password, instanceURL, apiVersion)
  
description_Account <- reactive({
  A <- rforcecom.getObjectDescription(session, "Acount")
  A})
  

output$table_1 <- renderDataTable({
  description_Account()
})  
  }) @Last Khajiit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found solution. I had this error:

> Error in rforcecom.login(username, password, instanceURL, apiVersion)
>   :    LOGIN_MUST_USE_SECURITY_TOKEN: Invalid username, password,
>   security token; or user locked out. Are you at a new location? When
>   accessing Salesforce--either via a desktop client or the API--from
>   outside of your company’s trusted networks, you must add a security
>   token to your password to log in. To get your new security token, log
>   in to Salesforce. From your personal settings, enter Reset My Security
>   Token in the Quick Find box, then select Reset My Security Token.

I reseted my security token in Salesforce. I had new Salesforce security token . I just added a security token to my password and my app works.